# Не работает вычисление расхождения массивов.

Tags: php, массивы

Всем, привет! Помогите пожалуйста понять, почему не работает функция вычисления расхождения массивов в моем примере.

---

То, как я получаю **ПЕРВЫЙ** массив:

```
$array_data = array();

foreach ($response['data'] as $data) 
{
    $created_time = $data['created_time'];
    $thumbnail = $data['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
    $tags_name = $data['tags'];

    $array_data[] = array
    (
        'DATE_PIC' => $created_time,
        'LINK_PIC' => $thumbnail,
        'TAG_PIC'=> $tags_name,
    );
}
```

Содержимое **ПЕРВОГО** массива:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380095187 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/95567b0025b611e3828a22000a9f191e_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [1] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380077949 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/72d65c62258e11e3af2822000ab6843e_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)
```

---

То, как я получаю **ВТОРОЙ** массив:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DATE_PIC, LINK_PIC, TAG_PIC FROM INSTA_PICTURE';
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$dbARRreturn = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($res))
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
            $one_piece = array();
            $one_piece['DATE_PIC'] = $row['DATE_PIC'];
            $one_piece['LINK_PIC'] = $row['LINK_PIC'];
            $one_piece['TAG_PIC'] = $row['TAG_PIC'];
            $dbARRreturn[] = $one_piece;
    }
}
```

Содержимое **ВТОРОГО** массива:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380739217 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/15448b462b9211e390a522000a9e17a0_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [1] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1378554164 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/9c78483017b211e3b12422000a1f901a_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [2] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1376411183 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/17fe2c90043511e3a96422000a1fbc12_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)
```

---

Вычисляю разность массивов (сразу замечу, что по идее разностью будет, содержимое первого массива)

```
$ARRresultMerge = array_diff_assoc($array_data, $dbARRreturn);
```

Содержимое результата разности **$ARRresultMerge**

```
Array ( )
```

*НУ КАК ТАК-ТО....????? Помогите, пожалуйста!!!*

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-assoc.php) Замечание:  Эта функция обрабатывает только одно измерение n-размерного массива. Естественно, вы можете обрабатывать и более глубокие уровни вложенности, например, используя array_diff_assoc($array1[0], $array2[0]);.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov а может подскажите еще вот [здесь][1]? :), пожалуйста!
[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/258063/php-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикле вам нужно сравнить каждый объект первого массива с каждым объектом второго:

```
$res = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key1 => $value1){
  $found = false;
  foreach($arr2 as $key2 => $value2){
    if (count(array_diff_assoc($value1,$value2))==0){
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!$found){
    $res[] = $value1;
  }
}
```

ЗЫ По поводу второго вопроса, там у вас ошибка, надо `$array_data = array();` из цикла вынести просто. Не знаю уж как у вас пять массивов получилось, по идее должен получиться только один и притом с одним элементом.
ЗЗЫ я не php'ист, мог что-то сморозить )

Comment: вот, да, примерно то, что надо было ) спасибо!

Comment: да и кстати, действительно помогло ))) вынес $array_data = array() за пределы цикла и все окей стало )), магия 80 лвл