# Объединить многомерные массивы

Tags: php, массивы

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как объединить несколько массивов в один.

Есть цикл *do-while*, который за каждый новый проход создает новый массив. Вопрос: Как объединить эти массивы?

---

Цикл **do-while**:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    //  Создадим массив данных из response
        $array_data = array();

        foreach ($response['data'] as $data) {
            $created_time = $data['created_time'];              
            $thumbnail = $data['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
            $tags_name = $get_TagIMG;

            $array_data[] = array
            (
                'DATE_PIC' => $created_time,
                'LINK_PIC' => $thumbnail,
                'TAG_PIC' => $tags_name,
            );
        }   
    $i++;

    } while ($i < 5);
```

---

После окончания цикла, получим пять массивов, примерно такого вида:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380488912 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/4c39144e294b11e3bef022000a1f9245_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)

Array (
    [1] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380489222 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/04ca9032294c11e3b53822000a1f96e6_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)

Array (
    [2] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380492460 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/8e755dd8295311e3a53722000aeb43de_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)

Array (
    [3] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380718591 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/0f8bcf142b6211e3982822000ae90f30_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)

Array (
    [4] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380717412 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/507c69fa2b5f11e3a7d422000a9e0846_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)
```

---

*Наверное как-то надо объединять новый с предыдущим при каждом проходе...*

---

В итоге должно быть примерно так:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380488912 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/4c39144e294b11e3bef022000a1f9245_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [1] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380489222 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/04ca9032294c11e3b53822000a1f96e6_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [2] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380492460 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/8e755dd8295311e3a53722000aeb43de_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [3] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380718591 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/0f8bcf142b6211e3982822000ae90f30_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [4] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380717412 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/507c69fa2b5f11e3a7d422000a9e0846_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)
```

Comment: когда мы слышим "многомерный массив" мы сразу говорим **РЕКУРСИЯ**

вот вы, любители `do {} while()`, чем вас for()  не устраивает ?

Comment: @eicto в общем, пойдет и FOR главное чтоб с... заработало )

Comment: @eicto дополнил вопрос

Comment: давайте вы сделаете пример со входными данными на ideone. потому-что сейчас не понятно что куда объединять.

Comment: так вы просто распечатайте ваш массив с json_encode... учитесь выделять проблемы :)

Comment: @eicto мне просто надо, что-то типо array_merge, выглядит так, цикл прошел первый раз, получил массив, этот массив сохраняем куда-то или держим "в памяти" (пошел на ум), второй проход, снова массив, берем массив который в уме и объединяем с новым и снова "пошел на ум", третий проход, получаем новый массив, берем массив который "в уме"(состоящий из первого и второго) и снова прибавляем третий и т.д.

Comment: вот что вам мешает сразу нужный массив то собирать ? Сделайте нормальный вопрос, ваша проблема проста, вы не можете решить её, просто потому что, вы не можете понять задачу сами.

Comment: @eicto сделано!

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за участие! Проблема решилась совсем просто! @eicto навел на мысль, а @Yura Ivanov дал [правильный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/258047/php-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2), в итоге нужны было всего-то вынести **$array_data = array();** за цикл, и как сказал @eicto - *сразу нужный массив то собирать*.